# NestJs creating a custom service for logging - not printing the output

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I am trying to create a NestJs service that will extend a Logger. However it is not printing the desired output (eg, super.warn(); see below for details). I believe what I am doing is pretty much the tutorial from nestjs site, but I cannot seem to get it working. https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/logger#using-the-logger-for-application-logging

```
I want to use custom logging.
src
  - a module
     - a.service.ts
     - a.module.ts
  - log module
     - log.service.ts // my custom log service
     - log.module.ts
  - PlainLogger (no module, no @Injectable(), just a plain class)
```

A.service.ts ( I am running a.service.spec.ts to test the output of log)

```
a.service.ts

@Injectable()
export class AService {
 
private readonly plainLogger = new PlainLogger()

constructor(private logService: LogService) {
   this.logService.setContext("some context")
}   

aMethod() {
  // plainService.meow("some input") This behaves as expected
  this.logService.meow("some input"); 
 }   
}
```

My log.service.ts

```
    import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

    @Injectable({scope:Scope.TRANSIENT})
    export class LogService extends Logger {

    meow(message:string) {
       super.warn(message) // This does NOT get printed. My goal is to get this printed.
       Logger.warn("static warning") // This gets printed
       return 1337
    }
  }
```

From looking at it, super.warn(...) does not seem to print out the log in the terminal, but if I use **PlainLogger, which basically has the same method**(except it is just a plain class without any module, and it doesn't have @Injectable annotation) as my custom log service.

From the tutorial link I posted, it seems possible to create a log service, but I am not quite sure what is wrong. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: It could be an issue with BufferedLogs, some libraries have it, trying different {bufferLogs: true} options could work others, like [here](https://github.com/iamolegga/nestjs-pino/issues/553#issuecomment-924577422) had to flush the logs manually. 
If you are testing then make sure you are not overwriting the logger, when creating calling the createTestingModule().     
Try running jest with the option  `--verbose false`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that logs do get printed by calling services (eg, calling service via a controller, but simply running the specs (test file) does not seem to work.